# Localhost is forbidden when using LAN IP address instead of 'localhost'

Tags: router, ip, port, android, wamp

I'm trying to access my localhost from my Android tablet, but I'm having problems. I'm using WAMP server and configured the httpd.config file, and port forwarded 80, but I still can't access localhost using my local IP address.

My local IP address is 192.168.1.24 according to ipconfig, but this brings up a 403 forbidden when I try to access it from both my computer and my tablet. Accessing 'localhost' from the PC works, but not from the tablet.

What is happening?

Comment: Do you have apache running on your android?

Comment: I don't, but judging from all the tutorials I tried I shouldn't need it. Apache is running on my PC with WAMP, and I'm just trying to connect to my PC localhost as opposed to host one off the Android. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Left Click on WAMP Server Icon in System Tray, Choose "Put Online".
Now check on your Andoid, it won't show 403 Forbidden Page.

Answer (score 1):

localhost will not work on your Android because that would mean your Android would be trying to connect to itself rather than the computer.

port forwarding shouldn't matter in this case, because you're doing locally. are your Android device and your PC on the same network?

I would double-check your Apache configuration and make sure it will accept connections from other devices, and maybe double-check your computer's IP address from the router's control panel just to be safe. (in rare cases, ipconfig can report the wrong address)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what are the parts of the Apache config that I should be checking (I don't understand most of it)?

Comment: take a look at this question on Stack Overflow, it seems to be the same issue that you're having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message

Answer (score 0):

Also you may need to look up for file [username].conf where need to include the directive Require all granted, as this file overrides http.conf
This file is located on /etc/apache2/users
Ensure you make this change in all necessary user files, including guest.conf

Comment: This has nothing to do with the accessing `localhost` from another machine.

Answer (score -1):

Localhost means address `127.0.0.1` that address is a special address that points back at the network adapter that generated the request. When you tried to access the page via `192.168.1.24` it saw that the request was going to a different address than `127.0.0.1` and rejected it on the PC. When you attempted to connect to it on your tablet your tablet just attempted to connect to itself.

What you need to do is change the configuration of the server to allow connections via your PC's address of `192.168.1.24`, not just the local host address.

Comment: "What you need to do is change the configuration of the server to allow connections via your PC's address"
And how ?!

Comment: @Black I don't know, never used WAMP before. Mainly I am going from my experience with IIS servers.